# How to send and receive messages asynchroniously via tcp

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

i'm making tcp-client with rust and tokio and i came down to this solution:

```
async fn main() {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("localhost:8080").await.unwrap();

    //let mut reader = BufReader::new(reader);

    loop {
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let (reader, mut writer) = stream.split();
            let mut line = String::new();
            let mut line_write = String::new();

            let mut reader = BufReader::new(reader);

            loop {
                tokio::select! {
                    result = reader.read_line(&mut line) => {
                        result.unwrap();
                        print!("{line}");
                    }
                    result = std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut line_write) => {
                        result.unwrap();
                        writer.write_all(line_write.as_bytes());
                        println!("sended!");
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but this one doesn't work because stdion().read_line() doesnt implement future trait, so i'm curious and i want to know how to rewrite this code so it will work and either receiving or sending messages

Comment: `tokio::io::stdin()` exists

Comment: @PitaJ It should not be used for interactive purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to spawn a thread (not a task or a blocking task! stdin is blocking and using a blocking task will prevent the application from shutting down properly) that reads from stdin and sends the data read to a channel. Then you can read from the channel:

```rust
use std::io::BufRead;

use tokio::io::{AsyncBufReadExt, AsyncWriteExt, BufReader, BufWriter};
use tokio::net::TcpStream;
use tokio::sync::mpsc;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let stream = TcpStream::connect("localhost:8080").await.unwrap();

    //let mut reader = BufReader::new(reader);

    let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(10);

    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut stdin = std::io::stdin().lock();
        loop {
            let mut line = String::new();
            stdin.read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
            tx.blocking_send(line).unwrap();
        }
    });

    let mut stream = BufWriter::new(BufReader::new(stream));

    let mut line = String::new();
    loop {
        line.clear();
        tokio::select! {
            result = stream.read_line(&mut line) => {
                result.unwrap();
                print!("{line}");
            }
            result = rx.recv() => {
                let line_write = result.unwrap();
                stream.write_all(line_write.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();
                println!("sended!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not work, message isn`t sended

Comment: okay i fixed this, i just needed to split stream to reader and writer

Comment: @tailaitailai This should work without splitting.